# MySQL "Column count doesn't match value count" but the count DOES match

Tags: mysql

MySQL is issuing this error when I try to execute a query where the column count does match. Here is the structure of the table:

```
mysql> desc S_3068; 
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| SfmID             | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 1       |       | 
| DatValue          | float                | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
| DatRawValue       | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
| DatTime           | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       | 
| DatBusOrder       | tinyint(3) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | 1       |       | 
| DatFormulaVersion | tinyint(3) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I get the aforementioned error when I execute this query:

```
mysql> insert ignore into S_3068 values (133, 15.82, 5542, 1339309260, 0, 1); 
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

As you can see, the column count does match the value count. Now what's even more puzzling is that the query works perfectly fine with SfmID = 132:

```
mysql> insert ignore into S_3068 values (132, 15.82, 5542, 1339309260, 0, 1); 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

SfmID being a unsigned smallint, that doesn't make any sense to me.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The error was caused by a trigger associated to the table. Please see comments for more information.

Comment: Not sure what it was supposed to do but this worked fine (status OK) and still the query fails with the same error.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly list the columns (I can't see why that would make a difference, but it might help to narrow down the source of the problem)?

Comment: Did you type the command into the `mysql` command line client using only the keyboard; or have you pasted it from elsewhere?  Perhaps there is a non-printing character in there which is causing a comma to be misinterpreted for some other character...

Comment: Using `INSERT` without specifying the columns e.g.: `Insert into s_3068 (sfmid, datvalue...) values ... (` is a bad coding style. You should always explicitely state the column names

Comment: What version of MySQL?  [This bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21774) in 5.0.24 looks plausible.

Comment: Check if there's any triggers defined on the table

Comment: You're right: There was a trigger associated to the table, doing a side insert on another table for value 133 but not for value 132. As usual with MySQL, a bit more information with the error message would have helped... Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @FrançoisIngelrest - Please use this as an opportunity to post the solution as an answer to your question, so that it can ge used by other in the future! We're happy you found what was wrong, but would be even happier if others could find what was occuring based on your experience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was caused by a trigger associated to the table, doing a side insert on another table for value 133 but not for value 132. The error issued by MySQL was about the other table (which column count was indeed wrong) and not about the main table in which I was inserting data.