# MySQL: Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count

Tags: mysql

UPDATE **  Thank you for everyone's help.  It is appreciated.  It was a trigger that was being used, and not an issue with the Insert.  I had tunnel visioned on the insert and forgot all about checking the trigger.

---

I can't for the life of me figure out the problem with this mysql insert:

```
INSERT INTO campaigns (camp_id,camp_name,camp_desc,camp_created,camp_creator,camp_start,camp_end,camp_active)
VALUES (null,'Clinic','2013 Clinic',now(),'user','2013-10-21','2013-10-25',1);
```

Table:

```
Field           Type          Null    Key   Default             Extra
===========================================================================================
camp_id         int(12)       NO      PRI               auto_increment
camp_name           varchar(32)   NO            
camp_desc           varchar(255)  YES           
camp_created    timestamp     NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
camp_creator    varchar(16)   NO            
camp_start      date          NO            
camp_end        date          NO            
camp_active         int(1)        NO
```

Any help is appreciated.

Per Requests:  SHOW CREATE TABLE campaigns:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` 
( `camp_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `camp_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `camp_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `camp_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `camp_creator` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `camp_start` date NOT NULL,
  `camp_end` date NOT NULL,
  `camp_active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`camp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: A lack of inverted commas I suspect

Comment: Just checking: Is that your actual query, copy-and-pasted and accurate to the letter?

Comment: Possibly related, if you have a trigger on this table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967063/mysql-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-but-the-count-does-match?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes around your dates

```
INSERT INTO campaigns( camp_id, camp_name, camp_desc, 
                       camp_created, camp_creator, camp_start, 
                       camp_end, camp_active)
VALUES (null, 'Clinic', '2013 Clinic',
        now(), 'user', '2013-10-21',
        '2013-10-25', 1);
```

If you still have errors and especially the `"Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count"` error, then the most probable explanation is a trigger that tries to do another Insert.

Comment: Any insight why this would cause the "column count doesn't match value count" error? All it would do without the quotes is try to insert the integers `1982` and `1978` into `camp_start` and `camp_end`, respectively, no? (assuming my math is right, but you get the idea)

Comment: I had them in originally, and gotten taken out in my fiddling.  :-)  I added them back into the question, to avoid confusion. I'm still getting the same error, with the quotes around the dates.

Comment: Is there an Insert trigger on the table? Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE campaigns;` output in your question.

Comment: Got it.  It was the trigger.  I just dropped the trigger and the insert went through fine. Thanks to everyone's help.  How should I best mark this answered?

Comment: Maybe @ypercube likes to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the error answered by juergen, you will also face an issue where you are having a column named `camp_id` which you have declared as `NOT NULL` and you are inserting `NULL` to it.

IF camp_id is Auto Increment then
Try this::

```
INSERT INTO campaigns( camp_name, camp_desc, 
                       camp_created, camp_creator, camp_start, 
                       camp_end, camp_active)
VALUES ('Clinic', '2013 Clinic',
        now(), 'user', '2013-10-21',
        '2013-10-25', 1);
```

Comment: Yeah...there's the other sticking point.  The camp_id is an auto_increment.  I've tried putting null, '', and omitting the field altogether and still get the same error.

Comment: Made the above change, but same issue, unfortunately.